# SSH tunnel for VNC through IP forwarding?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, vnc, port-forwarding

I'm trying to setup a VNC connection from my local desktop to another machine. I'm having some difficulties with how to setup the port forwarding I need to make it work.

The machine setup is like this:

```
-----------     -----------     -----------        -----------
|Machine A|---->|Machine B|---->|Machine C|   ---->|Machine D|
-----------     -----------  |  |         |   |    -----------
                             ---|-port X--|----
                                -----------
```

Each machine is only accessible from the previous one.

1. A is my local machine. I have root access
2. From A, I can connect to B. I don't have root access on B but I have a user account.
3. From B, I can ping C and use it as a router because port X on it has been setup to forward to D through an iptables rule. I don't have access to C.
4. D is the intended target to host the VNC server

How would I do this?

Comment: **https://superuser.com/questions/96489/an-ssh-tunnel-via-multiple-hops**

Comment: Or use a jump host http://blog.remibergsma.com/2013/05/28/creating-a-multi-hop-ssh-tunnel-by-chaining-ssh-commands-and-using-a-jump-host/

Comment: I did see that first link you posted. I'm using the ProxyJump method right now for an ssh connection to machine D, which works great. Maybe I'm missing something, but how does this work here where I need to forward port 5901 on D back through to A? I can't connect to C directly and D is only accessible through one port on C.

Comment: Do you mean how to configure *iptables* like in https://medium.com/@TarunChinmai/sharing-internet-connection-from-a-linux-machine-over-ethernet-a5cbbd775a4f or https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-demilitarized-zone-howto/

Comment: Now i undertand, because C forwards 5901 of D you see D directly from B. What you have to do to see it on A is to set iptables rules on **B** so that A sees D directly (via B and C that simply forward all traffic by iptables rules). This is similar to digging tunnel, this is why it is called ssh tunnel. Basically the iptables rules on B are similar to those on C